# Google Drive Rest API authentication issue after entering id, secret, and key

Tags: php

I want to use Google Drive rest Api to list the files on the drive. But there is an authentication problem.

I enter the Client Id , Client secret, and Api key but it's not working. I use the library.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
function get_gdrive_file_list($operation) {

            include(VIS_PATH_PLUGINS.'gmail_login/src/Google_Client.php');
            include(VIS_PATH_PLUGINS.'gmail_login/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php');
            $client = new Google_Client();

                $client->setClientId('****************************');
                $client->setClientSecret('**********************');
                $client->setRedirectUri('**********************');
                $client->setDeveloperKey('*********************');
                $cal = new Google_DriveService($client);


                if (isset($_SESSION['code'])) {
                $client->authenticate($_SESSION['code']);
                $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
                unset($_SESSION['code']);
                }
                if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
                $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
                }

                if ($client->getAccessToken()) {


                $calList = $cal->files->listFiles();        
                echo "Result : ";echo "<pre>";print_r($calList);echo "</pre>";echo "<br>";
            }

        } ?>
```

Comment: What is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: [responseBody:protected] => {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}

Comment: This array after the the following function    static public function execute(Google_HttpRequest $req) {
    $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest($req);
 echo "httpRequest IN THE GOOGLE REST : ";echo "<pre>";print_r($httpRequest);echo "</pre>";echo "<br>";
 
    $decodedResponse = self::decodeHttpResponse($httpRequest);
 
    $ret = isset($decodedResponse['data'])
        ? $decodedResponse['data'] : $decodedResponse;
    return $ret;
  }

Comment: Can i give the permissions to gmail account  , not admin account for checking purpose .Permissions for sharing drive files. I tried but it  asked for the admin account.Please tell me wt should i have to do.

Comment: An error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Comment: Please [edit that information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39125629/edit) into your question itself.